# Virtuemart cart string structure in database

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I'm using the Joomla's extension Virtuemart 1.1.9 with joomla 1.5 to create my shopping cart.  With the help of another component, I can upload a plain text file to the server with the Product Id and the quantity.  With the following routine I can conolidate the load into the cart.

The problem with this method is that when I proceed to place the order, the products prices don't multiply with the quantity ordered to obtain the total of the order.

Any ideas?

here is the code

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
declare producto, cantidad, cliente, carga, categoria int;
declare cantidadreg, cuenta, i int default 0;
declare cadena text default "";
declare varcarga int default 0;

declare cur1 cursor for select jos_vm_product.product_id, cant_producto, id_cliente, datos_cargas_vm.id_carga, category_id
from datos_cargas_vm inner join cargas_vm on datos_cargas_vm.id_carga=cargas_vm.id_carga
inner join jos_vm_product on datos_cargas_vm.id_producto=jos_vm_product.product_sku
inner join jos_vm_product_category_xref on jos_vm_product.product_id = jos_vm_product_category_xref.product_id
where estado_carga='P'
order by datos_cargas_vm.id_carga, jos_vm_product.product_id;

declare continue handler for not found set done = true;

open cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
    fetch cur1 into producto, cantidad, cliente, carga, categoria;

    if done then
        leave read_loop;
    end if;

    if varcarga!=carga then
        select count(*) into cantidadreg from datos_cargas_vm inner join cargas_vm on datos_cargas_vm.id_carga=cargas_vm.id_carga
        inner join jos_vm_product on datos_cargas_vm.id_producto=jos_vm_product.product_sku
        inner join jos_vm_product_category_xref on jos_vm_product.product_id = jos_vm_product_category_xref.product_id
        where estado_carga='P' and datos_cargas_vm.id_carga=carga;

        set varcarga:=carga;
        set cadena:=concat("a:",cast(cantidadreg+1 as char),":{s:3:\"idx\";i:",cast(cantidadreg as char),";");
        set i:=0;
    end if;

    set cadena:=concat(cadena,"i:",cast(i as char),";a:5:{s:8:\"quantity\";i:",cast(cantidad as char),
        ";s:10:\"product_id\";s:5:\"",cast(producto as char),"\";s:9:\"parent_id\";i:",cast(producto as char),
        ";s:11:\"category_id\";i:",cast(categoria as char),";s:11:\"description\";s:0:\"\";}");
    set i:=i+1;

    if i=cantidadreg then
        set cadena:=concat(cadena,"}");
        -- select cantidadreg,cadena;

        select count(*) into cantidadreg from jos_vm_cart where user_id = cliente;

        if cantidadreg=0 then
            insert into jos_vm_cart(user_id,cart_content) values(cliente,cadena);
        else
            update jos_vm_cart set cart_content=cadena where user_id=cliente;
        end if;
        update cargas_vm set estado_carga='C' where id_carga=carga;
    end if;
END LOOP;

close cur1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to bypass all the virtuemart logic to load the cart, you're likely going to have to emulate it and do the math at the same time as the load.